# Issue getting img element to display when positioned over another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an SVG element that acts as a container for a chessboard I created. I need to have an interact-able component pop up during key moments of the game, such as when a pawn promoted and a player needs to select which piece he desires. I cannot store this component as a child of the chessboard container, because the chessboard needs to be disabled while the user is selecting which piece they want. therefore my current decision was to create an IMG element containing all the selectable pieces. I overlayed the IMG element over the svg element using the img's position:absolute and top/left properties. I then attach an eventListener to the document itself, disabling the eventlistener once the user selects what he needs. Assuming I have no bugs in my code, is this approach possible?

This is a simplified version of my code which also does not work:

pretend the blue square is the chess board:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>The img element</h1>

    <svg id = "cont" width = "500" height = "600">
      <rect width = "500" height = "600" style = "fill:blue">
    </svg>

    <script>
      var im = document.createElement("img");
      im.src = "img_girl.jpg";
      im.width = "250";
      im.height = "300;
      im.style = "position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px";
      document.body.appendChild(im);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The notification wouldn't be part of the board anyway. Just give it a higher z-index with absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible; when elements overlap, which one shows up on top is determined by the `z-index` CSS property, then by the elements' order in the document if the Z-indexes are equal.  The chessboard container might block the individual pieces from interacting with outside elements in this way, but you can at the very least overlay the new element over the entire chessboard container.

That said, I wouldn't recommend using a single IMG element to show a menu; there are other HTML elements that are better suited for that purpose.